# Unknown function generating fractal patterns in the form of Hofstadter's butterfly

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian, fractals

In the paper cited below, a certain unknown function $g(E)$ is responsible for the generation of the fractal pattern observed in the band spectrum of the Hamiltonian of the system:
$$
H=e^{ix}+ e^{-ix}+e^{ip}+e^{-ip}
$$
in the transformation:
$$
(\hbar, E)\longmapsto (4{\pi}^2/{\hbar}, g(E))
$$
I have not been able to find whether or not any papers have been published on the function's form, or it's physical significance. I would be grateful if you guys could help me out here.

Reference:

- Y. Hatsuda, H. Katsura and Y. Tachikawa, "Hofstadter's butterfly in quantum geometry",  New J. Phys. 18 (2016) 103023

Answer (score 0):

The generation of the fractal spectrum by the  recursive map is the main part of Hofstadter's original paper:

D. R.  Hofstadter,  *Energy levels and wavefunctions of Bloch electrons in rational and irrational magnetic fields*. Physical Review B. 14 (1976)  2239–2249; doi:10.1103/PhysRevB.14.2239

The author's of your paper also discuss something like this in [another paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0007067.pdf):